# Spring DispatcherServlet Complex Mapping

Tags: spring, servlets, servlet-mapping

I am trying to use Spring Boot to create an application that has the following:

A 3rd party HttpServlet needs to be mapped at "/data/*" to match the following:

- "/Patient" given as "/data/Patient"
- "/_services/*" given as "/data/_services/something"

Then I need to add a new service option. I wanted to do this using a RestController that was using the request mapping of "/data/_services/smart/".

In addition, I wanted other endpoints like "/health", "/management", to be served by the dispatcher servlet.  If I use the default dispatcher servlet mapped at "/" then "/health", "/management" work fine.

If I add a ServletRegistrationBean for the 3rd party servlet, requests like "/data/Patient", etc work fine.
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean data() {
        HapiFhirServlet servlet = new HapiFhirServlet(myAppCtx, metadataRepository);
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/data/*");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

But I am unable to map the RestController at "/data/_services/smart".  I am trying:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public ServletRegistrationBean smartServicesRegistrationBean(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/data/_services/smart/*");
}
```

As soon as I add this ServletRegistrationBean, the path "/data/_services/smart/*" works, the paths for the 3rd party servlet work, but the other dispatcher requests ("/health", "/management") fail.  It seems I can only have dispatcher at either "/" or "/data/_services/smart/*" but not both.

Can someone please advise?

Here is my Application class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, /*securedEnabled = true, */proxyTargetClass = true)
@Import({OAuth2ResourceConfig.class, MethodSecurityConfig.class})
@ComponentScan
public class HSPCReferenceApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer    {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext myAppCtx;

@Autowired
private MetadataRepository metadataRepository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HSPCReferenceApiApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(HSPCReferenceApiApplication.class);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean data() {
    HapiFhirServlet servlet = new HapiFhirServlet(myAppCtx, metadataRepository);
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/data/*");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public ServletRegistrationBean smartServicesRegistrationBean(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/data/_services/smart/*");
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't register a servlet on that URL. You just should register a controller in the normal dispatcher servlet. You shouldn't map a servlet just because you can.

Comment: The servlet is a 3rd party servlet that I have to use on the that URL.

Comment: No it is a dispatcher servlet.. You shouldn't map the `DispatcherServlet` to `/data/_services/smart` you should have a controller in the normal dispatcher servlet.